# Getting a alot of errors while creating the 2GP Unlocked Package

Tags: appexchange, package, unlocked-package, 2gp

While creating the Package version after a long wait of 'verifying  metadata' it shows me a lot of errors related to Apex classes, objects and their fields that this custom metadata doesn't exist in the scratch Dev Org.

Errors List:

```
(924) SPR_Report: Variable does not exist: Legacy_Category_Code__c
(925) SWRControllerTest: Variable does not exist: Tax_ID__c
(926) SWRControllerTest: Variable does not exist: Entity_Type__c
(927) SWRControllerTest: Variable does not exist: recordtypeid
(928) SchedulePaymentCATest: Variable does not exist: Tax_ID__c
(929) SendToProblemResolutionCtr_Test: Variable does not exist: Tax_ID__c
(930) SendToProblemResolutionCtr_Test: Variable does not exist: Entity_Type__c
(931) ServicesDeliveredHandlerTest: Variable does not exist: recordtypeid
(932) PurchaseOrderControllerEditTest: SELECT id, name, recordtypeid FROM account
                 ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:18
No such column 'recordtypeid' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
(933) SDOC__SDRelationship__c: Topics cant be enabled for this entityName: SDOC__SDRelationship__c
(934) Check_Record_Page: We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component sortablegrid:sdg.
(935) Contact_Record_Page: We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component CMTD:EnhancedRelatedList.
(936) Contact_Record_Page3: We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for component CMTD:EnhancedRelatedList*.
```

etc.

Kindly help me in this situation for creating this package. So we'll be able to upload our app to AppExchange.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK unlocked packages cannot be uploaded to the App Exchange; the latter is for managed packages only.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Can you [edit] your question to explain how you have structured the source tree (especially around custom fields and record types). Are these in the same "package directory" as the package itself? Showing your `sfdx-project.json` content would be helpful.

Comment: I'm able to resolve all previous errors but expect I'm not able to get Notes,----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This Errors ==>>
PurchaseOrderController: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: ContentNote

CaseActionPOEditController: AuraEnabled methods do not support the parameter type of ContentNote @PhilW